# Prove $E(X) = \sum_{j=1}^n E(X|X \in A_j) \mathrm{Pr}(X \in A)$

Tags: probability, expectation

I'm looking to prove:

Let X denote a real-valued random variable with range X, such that E(|X|) < $\infty$. Let $A_{1}$,...$A_{n}$ denote disjoint subsets of X. Show that

$E(X) = \sum_{j=1}^n E(X|X \in A_j ) \mathrm{Pr}(X \in A)$

However this equation is quite difficult to solve.

Comment: As it stands, you haven't given us enough information. What do we know about $X,$ $A,$ and the sets $A_j$? It's not difficult to find a counterexample for the claim as written. Please give us more context, including your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Further, I guess both $A_j$ and $A$ in the formula should be $A_i$?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in your formula. You want to prove

$$E(X)=\sum E(X|A_{j})P(A_{j})$$
instead, here $A_{j}$ is a sequence of events such that $P(\bigcup A_{j})=1$. But I think this follows from the definition of conditional expectation. Maybe checking your textbook will be helpful.

Update:
As pointed out by Did, there is an ambiguity. I think the classical formula $E(X|Y)$ is only making sense as the expectation of $X$ relative to $Y$, which means this is a function of $Y$. I suspect OP means $A_{j}$ to be a partition of the domain and $E(X|A_{j})$ is the expectation of $X|A_{j}$ on $A_{j}$. But then we have

$$E(X)=\int xf_{X}(x)dx=\bigcup \int_{A_{j}} xf_{X}(x)dx=\sum E(X|A_{j})P(A_{j})$$

The last equation follows because $X|A_{j}$ is the restriction of $f_{X}(x)$ at $A_{j}$ divided by $P(A_{j})$.

Comment: My apologies. 

Let X denote a real-valued random variable with range X, such that E(|X|) < $\infty$. Let $A_{1}$,...$A_{n}$ denote disjoint subsets of X.

Comment: "here Aj is a sequence of random variables" >> events. // "P(X∈Aj)" >> P(Aj)